# recreate Ft_putnbr_base in C. but, problem, no display

Tags: c

I tried to replicate the ft_putnbr_base function. But, when I want to run, nothing is displayed.

Here's what the function should do:

Write a function that displays a number in the terminal in a given base.

• The function must handle negative numbers. number is given as an int and the base as a string

◦ 0123456789 is the base commonly used to represent our numbers base contains all the symbols that can be used to display the number: decimals; ◦ 01 is a binary basis; ◦ 0123456789ABCDEF is a hexadecimal base; ◦ quickpony is an octal base.

• If a parameter contains an error the function displays nothing. An error can be: ◦ base is empty or is of size 1; ◦ base contains the same character twice; ◦ base contains the characters + or -. etc ...

here is my work :

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

int     ft_check_base(char *base)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;

    i = 0;
    while(base[i])
    {
        if (base[i] < 2)
            return (1);
        i++;
    }
        i = 0;
    while(base[i])
    {
        if (base[i] == '-' || base[i] == '+' || base[i] == ' '
        || (base[i] >= 9 && base[i] <= 13))
           return (1);
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (base[i])
    {
        j = 0;
        while (base[j])
        {
            if (base[i] == base[j])
                return (1);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}

void    ft_putnbr_base(int nbr, char *base)
{
    int base_size;

    if (ft_check_base(base) == 1)
        return;
    base_size = 0;
    while (base[base_size])
    {
        base_size++;
    }
    if (nbr < 0)
    {
        ft_putchar('-');
        ft_putchar(base[nbr / base_size]);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putchar(base[nbr / base_size]);
    }
}

int     main()
{
    ft_putnbr_base(8, "01");
}
```

`Display:`

Answer (score -1):

Try `printf()` of `<stdio.h>` in the `main()`.